# ArrayBased Stack Implementation pop() Is there any difference between s[top] = null, top-- and s[--top] = null?

Tags: java, data-structures

Hello Everybody and big thanks for any support given to me.

My Question is really short, and specific.

Straight away I attach operation pop(), related to ArrayStack Implementation.

```
public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    E temp = s[top];
    s[--top] = null;
    return temp;
}
```

According to Array-based implementation of Stack, the pop operation decrease top in this sentence:

```
s[--top] = null;
```

However i find this extremely confusing, why is it not simply this:

```
s[top] = null;
top--;
```

I understand both operation do the same job. However I can't figure out how is it done with `s[top--] = null`. Does it set `s[top] = null` and then follow `top--;`. Is this done in one step?

Thanks.

Full Class for Reference:

```
public class ArrayBasedStack {

protected E s[];
protected int top = -1;

public ArrayBasedStack(int cap){
    s = (E[]) new Object[cap];
}

public int size(){
    return top + 1;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(top < 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public E top() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
    }
    return S[top];
}


public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    E temp = s[top];
    s[--top] = null;
    return temp;
}

public void push(E element) throws FullStackException {
    if (size() == capacity){
        throw new FullStackException("Stack is full.");
    }
    S[++top] = element;
}
```

}

Comment: There is a difference because it's the other way around, but yes you can split that out.

Comment: What do you mean by other way around? could you explain in steps how java sees this sentence s[--top] = null;

Comment: `--top` decrements `top` and evaluates to the new value. `top--` decrements `top` but evaluates to the *old* value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.

Comment: `s[--top] = null;` I don't think that's right. you want to post-decrement, here.

Comment: it has to be    s[top--] = null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s[--top] = null;
```

decrements the index *first*, then indexes the array.

```
s[top] = null;
top--;
```

indexes the array, then *second* decrements the index. It also likely risks an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.